# How to configure certain programs to always open in full screen?

Tags: lxde, lubuntu, fullscreen

Under LXDE desktop manager <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> can be used to switch a program to full screen.

I use this shortcut so often that'd I rather have certain programs always open in full screen instead of doing it manually.

Is it possible to define some system configuration, or a shell script that'd always launch particular programs in full screen? (Particular not all because I wouldn't want certain small windows like network configuration window and system calendar to open in full screen).

Answer (score 6):

Put this in your `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` in between `<applications>` tags:

```
<application class="Firefox" name="Navigator">
    <fullscreen>yes</fullscreen>
</application>
```

---

To get specific `class` or `name` for your applications, use this:

```
obxprop | grep '^_OB_APP'
```

and then click with your cursor inside the app window.

---

Useful website: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration

Comment: Running obxprop gives me `_OB_APP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "lxpanel"  _OB_APP_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "panel"`. Not `firefox` and `Navigator` as you've specified.

Comment: @KshitizSharma did you click inside firefox window after running `obxprop`?

Comment: No. I was clicking on the firefox taskbar entry. Directly clicking inside the window works correctly.

Comment: However, after entering it into `lubuntu-rc.xml` it only works for `firefox`. Entries for `sublime text` and `chrome` don't result in full screen. Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. Here is an example snippet of the file: http://pastebin.com/Grb3Yehs

Comment: +1 I can confirm that this works. But it has a catch. For some programs it's making every window in the program as full screen. For example, in sublime text I'm getting the save file dialog as full screen.

Comment: @KshitizSharma you can add more specifications, this works for my sublime text: `<application class="Sublime_text" name="sublime_text" role="" type="normal">`

Answer (score 2):

Generally `lxde` will have a `rc.xml`/`lxde-rc.xml`/`lubuntu-rc.xml` inside `~/.config/openbox/`

Example contents of the `xml` file:

```
<application name="firefox">
  <fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
</application>
```

You should add the following line under your preferred application node (as shown above in the example):

```
 <fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
```

And execute `openbox --reconfigure`

Comment: This is not working.