# How to configure an application to be started in full screen mode?

Tags: fedora, fullscreen

I can find a similar topic:
[How to configure certain programs to always open in full screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217583/how-to-configure-certain-programs-to-always-open-in-full-screen), but it does not solve my question.

I wonder which aspect the question is related to, the distro, or the desktop session? I use the Fedora and Gnome 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install devilspie2 and create a config file ~/.config/devilspie2/max.lua with the following content, which would start every Iceweasel maximized:

```
-- Make Iceweasel always start maximized.
if (get_application_name() == "Iceweasel") then
  maximize();
end
```

[Src: readme](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/devilspie2.git/plain/README)

Then make sure to start devilspie2 together with your desktop environment.