# how to come back from fullscreen mode in gpicview

Tags: images

In an image browser called gpicview ( http://lxde.sourceforge.net/gpicview/ ) I can enable fullscreen mode by pressing a button with a square and four arrows. But how can I disable the fullscreen mode?

Comment: A search for LXDE and fullscreen gives me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/217583/203203

Comment: This is not what I ask about. My question is: I can enter fullscreen mode by pressing a button - but how then I can exit the fullscreen mode? Pressing the same button again does not make gpicview exit the fullscreen mode.

Comment: It's worth mentioning in your question that pressing the button again doesn't exit fullscreen mode. That would be a bug, then?

Answer (score 0):

Just pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> worked for me on Lubuntu 18.04 and Fedora 28 i3.

Answer (score 0):

Once you opened an image with GPicView:

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to go into fullscreen mode.

Once in fullscreen mode, press either <kbd>F11</kbd> again or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to windowed mode.